# Complained about boss to boss's boss now he left

Tags: management

I complained about my manager to her boss (taking too many sick leaves, she didn't make good decisions in the workplace) to her boss who I have a good relations with.  Now her boss is transfering to another department.  How can I deal with my manager now that her boss left and can't keep her in check?  She might have known I complained about her as well.  We already didn't have good relations and she is making work difficult.

Comment: Well, that's one reason why what you did is considered risky in office politics. You might need to look into being transferred internally or look for a new job. Staying with this manager could be career-limiting.

Comment: Did you consider the downsides prior to making the complaint? Now you have to choose what you do: stay and suffer or move on.

Comment: Maybe wait until there is a problem, and then approach that problem on its merits.

Comment: "now that her boss left and can't keep her in check?"  What makes you think her new boss can't keep her in check?

Comment: Is it your opinion that she took too many sick leaves or did she violate some policy?  It is generally not a good idea to go over your bosses head, especially in areas you may not have a authority to judge

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing specific you can do right now, aside from keeping your eyes open for other job opportunities.

If you don't know for certain that your complaint has been leaked to your manager, assume it hasn't, and continue working as always. If you are unhappy with the performance of your manager, I would first try to talk with the person in private. Make it about what holds you back, and what the manager could do different to enable your success. Only if that doesn't work, or if the manager takes part in gross misconduct, go to the next level manager. Even if the "managers manager" has transferred, there should be someone else filling that position shortly.

Side note: Complaining that someone "took too many sick leaves" is borderline harassment to me. If you are sick, you can't work. And you don't get to decide if you are sick or not. I would advise you to mind your own business. If you need to complain about colleagues, complain about stuff that's affecting you personally, not snitching about stuff that shouldn't concern you.

Comment: Huge support for the side note here.

Comment: don't start nuthin won't be nuthin

Comment: It could be harassment to treat someone who works for you this way, even worse to pass judgment up the chain.

Answer (score 1):

> *I complained about my manager to her boss*

and what happened? Did you receive any reply on that or it was more of a one-sided communication?

In case you did not hear any feedback / reply, and you already had travelled the road for escalation, it does not appear that your future journey with this manager is going to be any better.

As I see, you have two choices

- Find a new manager (either internally or external, some other organization) to work for.
- Use the above option.